# Which TLS library should I use, portability is an issue

Tags: c++, network-programming, ssl

We are looking to add TLS (transport layer security) support to our software, and are looking for the best choice of a library.
The software is written in c++, and is ported to Linux and Solaris (and Windows, but who gives a crap?).
Being able to adapt the code to both Linux and Solaris is a major concern, and thus a library which is known to work well on Solaris would be preferred, even at the cost of efficiency.

Thanks in advance for any recommendation.
Shai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used OpenSSL on Windows, AIX, Solaris, HPUX and Linux for quite a long time and never found any incompatibilities. As far as I remember, no platform specific code was needed to make it work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I'd vote you up had I remembered the login credentials to my actual account.

Answer (score 3):

[GnuTLS?](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) [An example.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/manual/html_node/Simple-client-example-in-C_002b_002b.html)

Comment: Do you have any experience running it on Solaris?

Comment: @user864940: Unfortunatelly I have no experience on this library.

Answer (score 0):

libssl works on Solaris. It's not fun to use but it's the de facto implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We've used OpenSSL on Windows with C++ but you'd have to check if this ports to all the Operating Systems that you need.